# Ruby returning "goodbye" unexpectedly

Tags: ruby, while-loop, break

So I wrote this code:

```rb
while true
  text = gets
  if text == "goodbye"
    puts "goodbye"
    break
  end
end
```

(I wrote it with indentation)
And when I type: Hello
It returns "goodbye" and the loop keeps on going?
Could somebody explain why?
And how to fix it?

I typed "goodbye" it returns "goodbye" and keeps on going.

Comment: With the code you posted: 1) It will never return "goodbye" nor will it print "goodbye" to the output stream because `text == "goodbye"` will never be `true`; 2) it will loop forever because of #1. `gets` will return the user input including the newline character e.g. `"goodbye\n"`. Given this either the description is wrong (less likely) or the code you posted is not the code you are running (more likely given the description).

Comment: `puts "goodbye"` and `break` are both inside the `if` statement. You can’t have one without the other. If the code prints "goodbye" it will also break the loop. Or it will not print it and keep looping.

Comment: The `gets` needs `chomp`ing.

Comment: You can debug this by doing a `p text`, so that you see exactly what is stored in the variable. `p` applies `inspect` to its argument, so it's useful for peeking into the internals of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to use `gets.chomp` because it will include a `\n` character on the string. I recommend you use `binding.pry` for debugging things like this

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Sadly the problem persists. When I type "Test" , it returns: "goodbye" and the loop doesnt break. Sorry for bad English. I will try to use the return statement instead of puts.

Comment: Edit: It works now!! My mistake! I removed puts "goodbye"

Comment: @justsomeguytrynasleep nice, now you should mark this as the answer (not just upvote)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take in count that gets catches the "\n".

So you can use:

```
break if text.include?('goodbye')
```

or

```
break if text.chomp.eql?('goodbye')
```